# Retrofit справедливо ругает

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Как я понял через данный запрос я получаю необходимый type из моей модели, но что то видимо упустил.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: IDEA сообщает, что у вас конструктор `DataAdapter()` ожидает `List<TextNumeric>`, а вы передаете `String`. Замените `new DataAdapter(jsonResponse.getTitle())` на `new DataAdapter(Collections.singletonList(jsonResponse))`

Comment: Предложило сделать модели TextNumeric implements List<TextNumeric>
ошибка пропала, но по мне так что то не то)

Comment: Обновил коммент.